# What is the difference between"dry oneself off" and "dry off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

Is there any difference between

> I dried off

And

> I dried myself off

Also would it change the meaning if we removed "off"?

Comment: **To dry** wouldn't normally be used intransitively, so it's almost always reflexive *I dried myself* if the object is the same as the subject. That's not the case with **to dry off**, where we assume the object is the same as the subject unless explicitly specified otherwise *(I dried **the dog** off)*. In short, either or both of ***myself*** and ***off*** are "optional" in your second example, without affecting the meaning significantly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't that an answer? It looks like one.

Comment: It's not a very complete answer. I could add, for example, that for me at least, *I dried **off*** is more likely in a "passive" context where I didn't really do anything to cause the drying, and *I dried **myself*** carries a stronger implication of taking "active" steps to make myself dry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is becoming more complete with every comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dry off" could be by any action -- the sun, the wind, etc.  "Dry *myself* off" suggests that *I* did it, presumably with something like a towel.

"Dry off" is generally synonymous with "dry"

> After falling into the lake, we **dried ourselves (off)** in front of the fire
>
> We hung up our clothes to **dry (off)** in front of the fire

Comment: We were obviously simultaneously making the very same fine distinction in my comment and your answer. I thought it might just be an "imho" thing - but it's always nice to find agreement on subtle points like this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation (both Andrew and FumbleFingers). Just for certain, "Dry off" could also mean I did it myself, couldn't it?

Comment: @MohamedSDarwish  Yes, but it implies that the action was passive, or that it's not important *how* you got dry.

Comment: @Mohamed: Yes. But in, say, *I dried off in the sun*, it's debatable whether you did it *yourself*, or simply allowed the sun to do it.